# How do I disable auto-accept for files received via Bluetooth?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

When accepting a picture via Bluetooth I accidentally enabled the checkbox `Always do this for Image files from ...`

Now pictures are always accepted from this device and I am unable to change the folder to save them in.

How can I reset this setting so the dialog appears again?

Answer (score 2):

### The Bluetooth stack

First of all, even though in Windows 7 the Bluetooth settings dialog always looks the same, there are at least two different Bluetooth stacks available which differ significantly in capabilities.

One of them (Microsoft/Widcomm/Broadcom?) can easily be recognized because it has the `Bluetooth Device Control` window that opens when you double click a Bluetooth device in `Devices and Printers`. This one is also the one that has the dialog mentioned in the question.

The other one (Toshiba?) features a "Receive file" entry in it's Bluetooth tray icon menu and does  *not* have these `Bluetooth Device Control` windows. **The question (and answer) does not apply to this kind of Bluetooth stack.**

### Reset the setting

#### The UI method

If you feel uncomfortable editing the registry there is a UI method to re-enable that dialog, however it's a bit cumbersome.

- First you need to pair the device in question.
- Then doubleclick it to open the `Bluetooth Device Control` window
- Scroll down to the `Authorization Options` section and expand it
- Switch to `Always allow this device to connect for all operations` and `Apply`
- Switch back to `Require confirmation for all operations to and from this Bluetooth device` and `Apply`
- You can now unpair the device again

The next time you send a picture from this device, the file receive dialog will appear and give you the chance to choose the destination folder for the received file again.

#### The Non-UI method

If you do feel comfortable editing the registry, it's much easier:

- Go to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Widcomm\BTConfig\Devices` (not `HKCU`, there is a very similar subtree there which I found to have no effect whatsoever)
- Find the device in question by it's MAC address or by doubleclicking the `Name` value
- Set the `ImageFileOption` (or `AudioFileOption`etc.) value to 0 (or just delete the whole device key to reset all setting to default)